# Error intentando buscar la primera letra y la primera vocal

Tags: javascript, regex

Ví otra pregunta que buscaba resolver como, de cualquier palabra, siempre mostrar la primera letra y la primera vocal, o sea:

```
"mapita" -> ma    
"astro" -> ao
```

```js
function palabra(w){
  var toArray = w.split(""),
      regex = /aeiou/i,
      i = 1,
      m = toArray.length,
      finalmente = [];
  for(;i<m;i++){
    if(regex.test(toArray[i])) {
      
      finalmente.push(toArray[0] + toArray[i]).join("");
      break;
  }  
  }
  return finalmente;
};

console.log(palabra("astronauta"))
```

Pero no entiendo cuál es mi error, ¿por qué no funciona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El principal motivo es tu regex. Estás diciendo que compare tu letra con "aeiou" no con cualquiera de esas vocales.

Por eso tu regex debería ser `/[aeiou]/i`.

Además no necesitas hacer un loop e ir mirando cada uno de ellos.

Puedes hacer hacer un `replace` de las consonantes por `""` para que te quedes con las vocales. La regex sería como la anterior pero con un `^` que es un NOT.

Quedaría  `/[^aeiou]/gi` añadiendo la flag `g` para que sea un replace global. (nota: has de añadir más caracteres si es que vas a lidiar con acentos)

Después solo tienes que imprimir el primer caracter y la primera vocal, teniendo en cuenta que si la primera vocal es la primera letra, coges la segunda vocal (eso parece estar pasando en tu test de "astro")

```js
function palabra(w) {

  var regex = /[^aeiou]/gi;
  var vowels = w.replace(regex, "");
  var len =  vowels.length;
  if(len > 1)
      console.log(w[0] + (vowels[0] == w[0] ? vowels[1] : vowels[0]));
  else
    console.log(w[0]);
}



palabra("astronauta")
palabra("mapita")
palabra("sr.")
palabra("al");
```

Answer (score 3):

Aceptá [la respuesta de lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/110685/127) que describe bien el problema de tu pregunta.

Agrego que así se puede resolver con una única expresión regular que capture a ambas:

```js
function primera(w) {

  let regex = /^.*?([a-záéíóúüñ])(?:.*?([aeiouáéíóúü]))?/i,
      resultado = w.match(regex);

  if (resultado) {
    return {
      letra: resultado[1],
      vocal: resultado[2]
    }
  }
}


//Pruebas
for (let prueba of ['astronauta', 'mapita', 'y', 'dr']) {
  console.log(primera(prueba));
}
```

Descripción:

```
/^.*?([a-záéíóúüñ])(?:.*?([aeiouáéíóúü]))?/i
```

- `^` - inicio del texto.
- `.*?` - cualquier cantidad de caracteres, cuantos menos sean necesarios (por si hay un caracter que no sea una letra al inicio).
- `([a-záéíóúüñ])` - primer grupo, por lo que captura el texto con el que coincide en `resultado[1]`. Coincide con:
  Una letra.
- `(?:.*?([aeiouáéíóúü]))?` - es un grupo opcional (por si no tiene una vocal luego de la primera letra). Coincide con:

  - `.*?` - cualquier cantidad de caracteres, cuantos menos sean necesarios.
  - `([aeiouáéíóúü])` - Grupo 2 que captura en `resultado[2]`. Coincide con:
    Una vocal.
- `/i` - ignora minúsculas y mayúsculas.